# Confirmation of transfer function of circuit with op amp

Tags: transfer-function

Hey I got an assignment on which I need to calculate the transfer function. It is about the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdK7XL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So my approach (note all capicitors values are the same and so referred to as  C):

1. At node A: i1 = i2 + i3 + i5
2. Ideal opamp so: i3 = i4
   $$\frac{Ua}{Zc}=-\frac{Uo}{R4}$$
   $$Ua=-\frac{UoZc}{R4}$$
3. Filling in 1.: 
   $$\frac{Ui-Ua}{Zc} = \frac{Ua}{R2}+\frac{Uo}{R4}+\frac{Ua-Uo}{Zc}$$

$$\frac{Ui+\frac{UoZc}{R4}}{Zc}=-\frac{\frac{UoZc}{R4}}{R2}-\frac{Uo}{R4}-\frac{\frac{UoZc}{R4}-Uo}{Zc}$$
$$UiZc+\frac{UoZc^2}{R4}=-\frac{UoZcR2}{R4}-\frac{Uo}{R4}-\frac{UoZc^2-UoZcR4}{R4}$$
$$UiZc=\frac{-UoZcR2-Uo-UoZc^2-UoZc^2-UoZcR4}{R4}$$
$$Ui=\frac{-UoZcR2-Uo-UoZc^2-UoZc^2-UoZcR4}{R4Zc}$$
$$\frac{Uo}{Ui}=\frac{R4Zc}{-2Zc^2-ZcR2-ZcR4-1}$$
$$Zc=\frac{1}{jwC}$$

$$\frac{Uo}{Ui}=\frac{jwCR4}{(jwC)(-jwC-R2-R4)-2}$$

So the question is is this correct? I hope it is however I tried testing my results by simulating the design in LTSpice, taking R4 = R2 = 1K and C = 1uF and then I entered the formula, with the same component values, in matlab however the graphs are not the same.. :(

[image: LT Spice]
[image: matlab]

**EDIT** Okay now it is confirmed the answer is wrong how would I derive such circuit? I tried it again but I'm yet again not getting the right answer.. I won't post it here since it takes to much time to type it out.

Comment: iVision, looking at your final function only one can see that it cannot be right: In the denominator you are summing "R" and "C". This is impossible!

Answer (score 1):

The formula for a multiple feedback high-pass filter should look like this: -

[image]

Don't worry about "s" if you've not come across it - replace it with jw but I can see your formula must be wrong i.e....

\$\frac{Uo}{Ui}=\frac{jwCR4}{(jwC)(-C-R2-R4)-2}\$

It can't be right because the jwC parts cancel out (top and bottom) leaving a TF that is not frequency dependent. Also the component names in your picture do not match your formula names.

The picture in my answer came from [this](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPtazyuHikeisan.htm) website and you can also use it to double-check any results because it uses a design tool where you plug in the values.

Comment: Okay it is wrong I see. But how would I derive it? And the jw doesn't cancel out, the two is outside the inner brackets, right?

Comment: Oh OK yes I see that - that makes a big difference. However I think the numerator shouldn't have jwC due to the definition of Zc if I follow your last two formulas correctly.

Comment: The 3rd line (point 3) is false (at least as far as the units are concerned): Uo/R4.

Comment: @LvW me or the OP?

Comment: Every time I try it I find a new mistake.. Is there any reference on solving such circuit? I found this one: http://extras.springer.com/2006/978-0-387-28340-1/wbapdx72.pdf it is a LPF one but I still fail to get the right result..

Comment: Andy aka, a 3rd line under point 3) can be found only in the OPs text.

Comment: @iVision I share your pain. Sometimes you need to derive stuff and a lot of time there is nothing to be found on the web that is either precise, easy to follow or easy to find. It can be a long slog uphill. Good luck.